Why is my Cython code is not faster than NumPy, and how can I optimize it?
I'm trying to improve the performance of some of my code by using Cython. However, I'm getting basically the same performance as the NumPy version. When testing the same code with Numba, the results are significantly faster than with Cython, so probably I am not using Cython correctly.
Here’s a brief overview of what I've tried so far:

Following Cython Documentation: I followed the "Working with NumPy" section in the Cython docs, but the performance didn't improve as expected.
Tried some tips from stackoverflow, but nothing specific enough that worth to mention.
Profiling: I tried running a profile following the Cython documentation, but the output was not helpful in identifying the bottleneck.The total time was basically {built-in method builtins.exec} (maybe this is important, but I'm unsure how to interpret it correctly).

Here's the code to reproduce my results:
Numpy Version (the same code shown in Numba, but without the @njit decorator):
import numpy as np

def numpy_optimize(psi: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    delta: float = 0.001
    lam: float = 0.01
    n_theta: int = psi.shape[1]
    n_samples: int = psi.shape[0]
    p: np.ndarray = np.eye(n_theta) / delta
    xi: list = []
    theta: list = 3*[[-0.0029283973561854606, 0.0032794468930772845, -0.003672579440695663]]
    for i in range(2, n_samples):
        psi_i = psi[i, :, None]# .reshape(-1, 1)
        p_psi_i = p.dot(psi_i)
        psi_i_T_p = psi_i.T.dot(p)
        k_numerator = p_psi_i / lam
        k_denominator = 1 + psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i) / lam
        k = k_numerator / k_denominator
        xi.append(y[i, 0] - psi_i.T.dot(np.array(theta[-1]))[0])
        theta.append(list(np.array(theta[-1]) + k.flatten() * np.array(xi[-1])))
        p_update_factor = psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i)
        p -= (p_psi_i.dot(psi_i_T_p)) / (p_update_factor + lam)
        p /= lam

    return np.array(theta[-1])

Cython Version:
%%cython

# Use the cell magic above to run in the notebook.
# The results are the same in the notebook as the one building cython code.
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()


def cython_optimize(cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] psi, cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] y):
    cdef int i
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] psi_i
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p_psi_i
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] psi_i_T_p
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] k
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p_update_factor
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p1
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p2
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p_numerator
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] k_denominator
    cdef int n_theta = psi.shape[1]
    cdef int n = psi.shape[0]
    cdef list theta = 3*[[-0.0029283973561854606, 0.0032794468930772845, -0.003672579440695663]]
    cdef double delta = 0.001
    cdef double lam = 0.01
    cdef list xi = []

    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] p = np.eye(n_theta) / delta

    for i in range(2, n):
        psi_i = psi[i, :, None]# .reshape(-1, 1)
        p_psi_i = p.dot(psi_i)
        psi_i_T_p = psi_i.T.dot(p)
        k_numerator = p_psi_i / lam
        k_denominator = 1 + psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i) / lam
        k = k_numerator / k_denominator
        xi.append(y[i, 0] - psi_i.T.dot(np.array(theta[-1]))[0])
        theta.append(list(np.array(theta[-1]) + k.flatten() * np.array(xi[-1])))
        p_update_factor = psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i)
        p -= (p_psi_i.dot(psi_i_T_p)) / (p_update_factor + lam)
        p /= lam

    return np.array(theta[-1]).reshape(-1, 1)

Numba Version:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba_optimize(psi: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    delta: float = 0.001
    lam: float = 0.01
    n_theta: int = psi.shape[1]
    n_samples: int = psi.shape[0]
    p: np.ndarray = np.eye(n_theta) / delta
    xi: list = []
    theta: list = 3*[[-0.0029283973561854606, 0.0032794468930772845, -0.003672579440695663]]
    for i in range(2, n_samples):
        psi_i = psi[i, :, None]# .reshape(-1, 1)
        p_psi_i = p.dot(psi_i)
        psi_i_T_p = psi_i.T.dot(p)
        k_numerator = p_psi_i / lam
        k_denominator = 1 + psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i) / lam
        k = k_numerator / k_denominator
        xi.append(y[i, 0] - psi_i.T.dot(np.array(theta[-1]))[0])
        theta.append(list(np.array(theta[-1]) + k.flatten() * np.array(xi[-1])))
        p_update_factor = psi_i_T_p.dot(psi_i)
        p -= (p_psi_i.dot(psi_i_T_p)) / (p_update_factor + lam)
        p /= lam

    return np.array(theta[-1])

The results are:
# creating arrays to test the functions
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(1000000, 1)
psi = np.random.rand(1000000, 3)

%timeit cython_optimize(psi, y_train)
16.3 s ± 164 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit numba_optimize(psi, y_train)
1.7 s ± 18.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit numpy_optimize(psi, y_train)
17.7 s ± 75.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
I'd appreciate if someone could help me in respect to:

What steps can I take to ensure that my Cython code is properly optimized?
How can I effectively profile my Cython code to identify and address performance bottlenecks?
What are some common mistakes or overlooked details when using Cython with NumPy that could lead to suboptimal performance?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Note: numpy==1.26.0, numba==0.59.1, and Cython==3.0.10

Numba does some optimisations on "whole array operations" (e.g. .dot, adding an array to another array). Cython doesn't and they're just regular Python function calls. The only thing that np.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=2] gives you in Cython is fast indexing of individual elements. You don't do any of that here.

To be more explicit, Cython just call regular Numpy functions like CPython does (i.e. with the same speed) while Numba completely reimplement Numpy (which means some functions are faster but some are also slower -- and Numpy function calls can be much faster since there is no Python-to-C calling overhead). For example, when you do p_psi_i / lam, it creates a new Numpy array by calling np.divide in Cython like for you Python script. It would be fast if you would use loops everywhere. In fact it can also be faster in Numba with loops too.

Only a single line makes this code 10.000 TIMES FASTER!!!
cimport cython
import cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np


np.import_array()
from time import perf_counter
import cv2 
# 4525 x 6623 x 3 picture https://www.pexels.com/pt-br/foto/foto-da-raposa-sentada-no-chao-2295744/
picpath = r"C:\Users\hansc\Downloads\pexels-alex-andrews-2295744.jpg"

pic=np.ascontiguousarray(cv2.imread(picpath))

cpdef tuple average_rgb_bad(np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=3] pic_original): 
    # NEVER LOOP THROUGH A NUMPY ARRAY LIKE THIS! NEVER EVER!
    # Typing is actually not important in the function declaration
    # The problem is here that we don't use a memory view! It is very slooooooooow 
    # Cython is such an awesome language, but the documentation is horrible. 
    # I struggled like you for a while, because the Cython documentation emphasizes 
    # the typing of NumPy arrays. It makes you think that using this,
    # is the key to success: np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=3]   But it isn't!
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t shape0_pic = pic_original.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t shape1_pic = pic_original.shape[1]
        Py_ssize_t i,j # Typing won't improve ANYTHING here! 
        # The whole function is crap, because we are not using MEMORY VIEWS!
        Py_ssize_t resultcounter=shape0_pic*shape1_pic
        Py_ssize_t r=0
        Py_ssize_t g=0
        Py_ssize_t b=0
    #with nogil: IS NOT POSSIBLE HERE, because you are calling Python functions/methods __getitem__ etc.
    start=perf_counter()
    for i in range(shape0_pic):
        for j in range(shape1_pic):
            b+=pic_original[i][j][0]
            g+=pic_original[i][j][1]
            r+=pic_original[i][j][2]
    print(perf_counter()-start)
    return b//resultcounter, g//resultcounter, r//resultcounter

cpdef tuple average_rgb_good(np.ndarray pic_original):
    cdef:
        # this changes everything! Just this little, tiny line. 
        # This creates a typed memoryview, and it
        # is blazingly fast! The function signature is very sloppily typed. 
        # But this is 10,000 TIMES FASTER THAN THE PREVIOUS FUNCTION!!!
        # Think about it as it were a C pointer to an array 
        # Now you can use this memoryview and operate on the original array. 
        # If you make changes to the view, you will make changes to pic_original as well  
        cython.uchar[:,:,:] pic = pic_original  # -> pure gold!
        Py_ssize_t shape0_pic = pic.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t shape1_pic = pic.shape[1]
        Py_ssize_t i,j
        Py_ssize_t resultcounter=shape0_pic*shape1_pic
        Py_ssize_t r=0
        Py_ssize_t g=0
        Py_ssize_t b=0
    start=perf_counter()
    with nogil: # there we go
        for i in range(shape0_pic):
            for j in range(shape1_pic):
                b+=pic[i][j][0]
                g+=pic[i][j][1]
                r+=pic[i][j][2]
    print(perf_counter()-start)
    return b//resultcounter, g//resultcounter, r//resultcounter

cpdef tuple average_rgb_very_good(np.ndarray pic_original):
    cdef:
        # This is a little faster, but use it only if you can guarantee 
        # that you are passing a continuous array!!
        # OpenCV, for example, does not guarantee continuous arrays when loading an image!! 
        #They are most of the time continuous, but sometimes not!
        cython.uchar[:,:,::1] pic = pic_original 
        # Always remember: when working with arrays / np.ndarrays,
        # you must somehow and somewhere use  square brackets with colons!
        # If you don't do that, your code will always be slow!!!
        Py_ssize_t shape0_pic = pic.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t shape1_pic = pic.shape[1]
        Py_ssize_t i,j
        Py_ssize_t resultcounter=shape0_pic*shape1_pic
        Py_ssize_t r=0
        Py_ssize_t g=0
        Py_ssize_t b=0
    start=perf_counter()
    with nogil:
        for i in range(shape0_pic):
            for j in range(shape1_pic):
                b+=pic[i][j][0]
                g+=pic[i][j][1]
                r+=pic[i][j][2]
    print(perf_counter()-start)
    return b//resultcounter, g//resultcounter, r//resultcounter



print(average_rgb_very_good(pic))
print(average_rgb_good(pic))
print(average_rgb_bad(pic))

# compiled with C division

# 0.015835800004424527
# (76, 83, 85)
# 0.01636139999027364
# (76, 83, 85)

# Now it becomes very clear that we haven't even left Python land 
# 123.76531680001062 # -> 10.000 times slower!
# cyimage2.pyx:37: RuntimeWarning: division with oppositely signed operands, C and Python semantics differ
  # r+=pic_original[i][j][2]
# cyimage2.pyx:37: RuntimeWarning: division with oppositely signed operands, C and Python semantics differ
  # r+=pic_original[i][j][2]
# cyimage2.pyx:37: RuntimeWarning: division with oppositely signed operands, C and Python semantics differ
  # r+=pic_original[i][j][2]
# (-66, -59, -58)

# it is also important to use the right compiler directives 
# Usually I use these:

comiler='''import numpy as np
from Cython.Compiler import Options
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import sys
import platform

iswindows = "win" in platform.platform().lower()
numpyincludefolder = np.get_include()
name = "cyimage2"

Options.docstrings = False
Options.embed_pos_in_docstring = False
Options.generate_cleanup_code = False
Options.clear_to_none = True
Options.annotate = True
Options.fast_fail = False
Options.warning_errors = False
Options.error_on_unknown_names = True
Options.error_on_uninitialized = True
Options.convert_range = True
Options.cache_builtins = True
Options.gcc_branch_hints = True
Options.lookup_module_cpdef = False
Options.embed = False
Options.cimport_from_pyx = False
Options.buffer_max_dims = 8


Options.closure_freelist_size = 8

configdict = {
    "py_limited_api": False,
    "name": name,
    "sources": [name + ".pyx"],
    "include_dirs": [
        numpyincludefolder,
    ],
    "define_macros": [
        ("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", 1),
        ("NPY_1_7_API_VERSION", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_DICT_VERSIONS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_FAST_GIL", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYLIST_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_UNICODE_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_ASSUME_SAFE_MACROS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_TYPE_SLOTS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_ASYNC_SLOTS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYLONG_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_UNICODE_WRITER", 1),
        ("CYTHON_UNPACK_METHODS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_EXC_INFO_STACK", 1),
        ("CYTHON_ATOMICS", 1),
    ],
    "undef_macros": [],
    "library_dirs": [],
    "libraries": [],
    "runtime_library_dirs": [],
    "extra_objects": [],
    "extra_compile_args": [],
    "extra_link_args": [],
    "export_symbols": [],
    "swig_opts": [],
    "depends": [],
    "language": "c",
    "optional": None,
}
compiler_directives = {
    "binding": True,
    "boundscheck": False,
    "wraparound": False,
    "initializedcheck": False,
    "nonecheck": False,
    "overflowcheck": False,
    "overflowcheck.fold": False,
    "embedsignature": False,
    "embedsignature.format": "c",  # (c / python / clinic)
    "cdivision": True,
    "cdivision_warnings": True,
    "cpow": True,
    "always_allow_keywords": False,
    "c_api_binop_methods": False,
    "profile": False,
    "linetrace": False,
    "infer_types": True,
    "language_level": 3,  # (2/3/3str)
    "c_string_type": "bytes",  # (bytes / str / unicode)
    "c_string_encoding": "ascii",  # (ascii, default, utf-8, etc.)
    "type_version_tag": False,
    "unraisable_tracebacks": True,
    "iterable_coroutine": True,
    "annotation_typing": True,
    "emit_code_comments": True,
    "cpp_locals": False,
    "legacy_implicit_noexcept": False,
    "optimize.use_switch": True,
    "optimize.unpack_method_calls": True,
    "warn.undeclared": True,  # (default False)
    "warn.unreachable": True,  # (default True)
    "warn.maybe_uninitialized": True,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused": True,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused_arg": True,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused_result": True,  # (default False)
    "warn.multiple_declarators": True,  # (default True)
    "show_performance_hints": True,  # (default True)
}
compdi = configdict
clidict = compiler_directives

ext_modules = Extension(**configdict)

setup(
    name=name,
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, compiler_directives=compiler_directives),
)

'''

Edit:
Generate always the source code report. That is the coolest thing in Cython.The disadvantage (or advantage, depends on how you see it) is that Cython always works! But if you don't follow Cython's rules, it can't do speedups for you.


Please don't micromanage macros like CYTHON_USE_DICT_VERSIONS - Cython selects these automatically based on the version of Python you're using. All you are doing with these is making it less future-proof rather than making it faster.

Thanks again @DavidW for your help! A while ago, I tested all different kinds and combinations of compiler directives over a weekend. As far as I remember, it gave a little speedup back then, but I might be mistaken! I will study it further!
